# Keeping the User logged in

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I want to keep my user logged in after their first log in until they log out by them self.

### heres my Main.dart

---

This is the screen when you first time opening the app.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: new MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SplashScreen(
      seconds: 5,
      navigateAfterSeconds: new AfterSplash(),
      imageBackground: AssetImage('assets/picture/splash.png'),
      loaderColor: Colors.red,
      loadingText: Text('Ver 2.0'),
    );
  }
}

class AfterSplash extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Sizer(
      builder: (context, orientation, screenType) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: FloatingNavBar(
            color: Colors.red[400],
            items: [
              FloatingNavBarItem(
                iconData: Icons.home,
                title: 'Home',
                page: HomeScreen(),
              ),
              FloatingNavBarItem(
                iconData: Icons.lock_clock,
                title: 'Riwayat',
                page: Bill(),
              ),
              FloatingNavBarItem(
                iconData: Icons.local_library,
                title: 'Info',
                page: Info(),
              )
            ],
            selectedIconColor: Colors.white,
            hapticFeedback: true,
            horizontalPadding: 60,
          ),
        );
        },
    );
  }
}
```

### and heres the screen after log in

---

this is the screen landing page when you logged in using the account.

```
class SPAL extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SPALState createState() => new _SPALState();
}

class _SPALState extends State<SPAL> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SplashScreen(
      seconds: 5,
      navigateAfterSeconds: new AfterSplash(),
      imageBackground: AssetImage('assets/picture/splash.png'),
      loaderColor: Colors.red,
      loadingText: Text('Ver 2.0'),
    );
  }
}

class AfterSplash extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Sizer(
      builder: (context, orientation, screenType) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: FloatingNavBar(
            color: Colors.red[400],
            items: [
              FloatingNavBarItem(
                iconData: Icons.home,
                title: 'Home',
                page: HSAL(),
              ),
              FloatingNavBarItem(
                iconData: Icons.lock_clock,
                title: 'Riwayat',
                page: Bill(),
              ),
              FloatingNavBarItem(
                iconData: Icons.local_library,
                title: 'Info',
                page: Info(),
              )
            ],
            selectedIconColor: Colors.white,
            hapticFeedback: true,
            horizontalPadding: 60,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

### and last the login screen

---

and this is the screen where you input the Username and the Password

```
TextEditingController emailController = new TextEditingController();
TextEditingController pwdController = new TextEditingController();

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _emailing = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _passwd = GlobalKey();
  String password = '';
  bool isPasswordVisible = false;
  bool _isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red[400],
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Login'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.h, horizontal: 2.h),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                'Masuk',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.sp),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1.h),
                child: Form(
                  key: _emailing,
                  child: TextFormField(
                      controller: emailController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'name@gmail.com/08XX-XXXX-XXXX',
                          labelText: 'Email/Nomor Hp',
                          // icon: Icon(Icons.mail),
                          suffixIcon: emailController.text.isEmpty
                              ? Container(width: 0)
                              : IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                                  onPressed: () => emailController.clear(),
                                ),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          focusColor: Colors.red),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                      // autofocus: true,
                      validator: (value) => value == null || value.isEmpty
                          ? "Masukan Email atau Nomor Hp Anda"
                          : null),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1.h),
                child: Form(
                  key: _passwd,
                  child: TextFormField(
                      controller: pwdController,
                      onChanged: (value) =>
                          setState(() => this.password = value),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Password',
                          labelText: 'Password',
                          suffixIcon: IconButton(
                            icon: isPasswordVisible
                                ? Icon(Icons.visibility_off)
                                : Icon(Icons.visibility),
                            onPressed: () => setState(
                                () => isPasswordVisible = !isPasswordVisible),
                          ),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                      obscureText: isPasswordVisible,
                      validator: (value) => value == null || value.isEmpty
                          ? "Masukan Password Anda"
                          : null),
                ),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                  child: Text(
                    'Lupa Password',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LupaPass()));
                  }),
              ButtonWidget(
                text: 'Submit',
                onClicked: () async {
                  if (_emailing.currentState.validate() &&
                      _passwd.currentState.validate()) {
                    LG();
                      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SPAL()),
                        (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
                      );
                  }
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### My Main Screen before Log-in

```
TextEditingController emailController = new TextEditingController();
TextEditingController pwdController = new TextEditingController();

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Stack(children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30.0.h,
                    width: 100.0.w,
                    child: DecoratedBox(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red[400],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Opacity(
                        opacity: 0.2,
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          child: Image.asset(
                            'assets/picture/indonesia.png',
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 22.5.h),
            child: Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 11.0.h,
                width: 95.0.w,
                child: DecoratedBox(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                        spreadRadius: 3,
                        blurRadius: 7,
                        offset: Offset(0, 0), // changes position of shadow
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0.h),
            child: Container(
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/Logo/iu.png',
                height: 15.h,
                width: 29.w,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6.0.h, horizontal: 2.5.h),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 60,
                  height: 60,
                  child: DecoratedBox(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                    child: Center(
                      child: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                          iconSize: 31,
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (_) => LoginScreen()));
                          }),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 17.5.h, horizontal: 3.0.h),
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Text('Indonesia ',
                            style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 20.sp,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                shadows: [
                                  Shadow(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    offset: Offset(-1.0, -1.0),
                                  ),
                                  Shadow(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    offset: Offset(1.0, -1.0),
                                  ),
                                  Shadow(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    offset: Offset(1.0, 1.0),
                                  ),
                                  Shadow(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    offset: Offset(-1.0, 1.0),
                                  ),
                                ])),
                        Text(
                          'Bisa',
                          style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 20.sp,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              shadows: [
                                Shadow(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  offset: Offset(-1.0, -1.0),
                                ),
                                Shadow(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  offset: Offset(1.0, -1.0),
                                ),
                                Shadow(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  offset: Offset(1.0, 1.0),
                                ),
                                Shadow(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  offset: Offset(-1.0, 1.0),
                                ),
                              ]),
                        )
                      ],
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          // Menu(),
          MLabel(),
          ICarousel(),
          Container(
              child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 56.0.h, left: 2.0.h, right: 2.0.h),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Sorotan',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 20),
                ),
                Text('Berita dan artikel yang sedang menarik baru - baru ini')
              ],
            ),
          )),
          GridHome()
        ])
      ])),
    ));
  }
}
```

### My Home Screen After Log-in

```
class HSAL extends StatefulWidget {
  final String nama, pass;
  const HSAL({Key key, this.nama, this.pass}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HSALState createState() => _HSALState();
}

class _HSALState extends State<HSAL> {

  SharedPreferences logindata;
  String username;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    initial();
  }
  void initial() async {
    logindata = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      username = logindata.getString('username');
    });
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Stack(children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30.0.h,
                    width: 100.0.w,
                    child: DecoratedBox(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red[400],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Opacity(
                        opacity: 0.2,
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          child: Image.asset(
                            'assets/picture/indonesia.png',
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 22.5.h),
            child: Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 11.0.h,
                width: 95.0.w,
                child: DecoratedBox(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                        spreadRadius: 3,
                        blurRadius: 7,
                        offset: Offset(0, 0), // changes position of shadow
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0.h),
            child: Container(
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/Logo/iu.png',
                height: 15.h,
                width: 29.w,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6.0.h, horizontal: 2.5.h),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 150,
                  height: 100,
                  child: DecoratedBox(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                            child: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                                color: Colors.red,
                                iconSize: 31,
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.push(context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => AkunInfo()));
                                }),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 15, left: 28),
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                            child: Text(
                              'Saldo',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 17,
                                  color: Colors.red),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Text(
                                'Rp\200.000',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                                    fontSize: 11.sp),
                              )),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                          child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                              child: SizedBox(
                                height: 3.h,
                                child: RaisedButton(
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  textColor: Colors.white,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                                  onPressed: (){
                                    Navigator.push(
                                        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => isiSaldo()));
                                  },
                                  child: Text('+ Isi Saldo'),
                                ),
                              )),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 17.5.h, horizontal: 3.0.h),
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Text('Indonesia ',
                            style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 20.sp,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                shadows: [
                                  Shadow(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    offset: Offset(-1.0, -1.0),
                                  ),
                                  Shadow(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    offset: Offset(1.0, -1.0),
                                  ),
                                  Shadow(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    offset: Offset(1.0, 1.0),
                                  ),
                                  Shadow(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    offset: Offset(-1.0, 1.0),
                                  ),
                                ])),
                        Text(
                          'Bisa',
                          style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 20.sp,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              shadows: [
                                Shadow(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  offset: Offset(-1.0, -1.0),
                                ),
                                Shadow(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  offset: Offset(1.0, -1.0),
                                ),
                                Shadow(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  offset: Offset(1.0, 1.0),
                                ),
                                Shadow(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  offset: Offset(-1.0, 1.0),
                                ),
                              ]),
                        )
                      ],
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          // Menu(),
          MLabel(),
          ICarousel(),
          Container(
              child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 56.0.h, left: 2.0.h, right: 2.0.h),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Sorotan',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 20),
                ),
                Text('Berita dan artikel yang sedang menarik baru - baru ini')
              ],
            ),
          )),
          GridHome()
        ])
      ])),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So how to do is simply add this code on the login button:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                    prefs.setString('email', emailController.text);
```

so itll look like this:

```
ButtonWidget(
                text: 'Submit',
                onClicked: () async {
                  if (_emailing.currentState.validate() &&
                      _passwd.currentState.validate()) {
                    LG();
                    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                    prefs.setString('email', emailController.text);
                      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SPAL()),
                        (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
                      );
                  }
                },
              ),
```

and this on the main.dart

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var email = prefs.getString('email');
```

and itll look like this :

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var email = prefs.getString('email');
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: email == null ?  new MyApp (): new SPAL()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

using [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) is an option here are the steps :

1. if the user is logged in and authentified correctly save a local variable indicating the user is logged in (could be Boolean or string)
2. every time the application opens and run check the stored variable
3. if the variable indicate the user was already logged in skip the sign in screen
4. else go to sign in screen.

here are some resources to help with `shared_preferences` :

- [reference one](https://petercoding.com/flutter/2021/03/19/using-shared-preferences-in-flutter/)
- [reference two](https://suragch.medium.com/saving-and-reading-data-in-flutter-with-sharedpreferences-bb4238d3105)

Update :
we need two methods you can define them in a new file and call it `localService.dart` for example :

```
//this is for saving a variable that means has logged in succefully  
Future<void> save_loggedIn() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString("loggedIn", "true");
}

//this is for checking the saved variable to check if the user is already logged in or not
Future<String> read_loggedIn() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var value = prefs.getString("loggedIn");
  return value;
}
```

now in main screen redirect is based on checking the loggedin variable in shared_prefrences :

```
Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: (read_loggedIn() == "true") ? new SPAL (): new MyApp()));
}
```

now in your logging screen add this line to save the variable in `shared_prefrences` :

```
        ButtonWidget(
                text: 'Submit',
                onClicked: () async {
                  if (_emailing.currentState.validate() &&
                      _passwd.currentState.validate()) {
                    // store the variable to remember that this user is logged in 
                    save_loggedIn();
                    LG();
                      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SPAL()),
                        (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
                      );
                  }
                },
              ),
```

Second Update :
i forgot to tell that you should add the `shared_prefrences` package in pubspec.yaml file :
version: 1.0.0+1

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences:
```

Comment: can you help me using the code i give?, I don't really understand it, im sorry im new to flutter

Comment: @Macchiato ok i'll update my answer with examples

Comment: @Macchiato just give me a moment , working on it right now

Comment: @Macchiato can you add your main screen please , i need that

Comment: @Macchiato this should give you an idea about shared_prefrences , i did not run the code on my side  so you might have some errors but this is the concept of using shared_prefrences

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233168/discussion-between-asmoun-and-macchiato).

Comment: theres no error on the Code but when i run it this happened `Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value`

Comment: Ill edit the Questions and add the error code