# Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value shared preference

Tags: flutter, dart

so I tried Shared preference to make user still logged in until they log out but when i tried to restart the app this appears

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
#0      MethodChannel.binaryMessenger (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:142:86)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:148:36)
#2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:331:12)
#3      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:358:49)
#4      MethodChannelSharedPreferencesStore.getAll (package:shared_preferences_platform_interface/method_channel_shared_preferences.dart:44:25)
#5      SharedPreferences._getSharedPreferencesMap (package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart:180:57)
#6      SharedPreferences.getInstance (package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart:56:19)
#7      read_loggedIn (package:indonesia_bisa_2/API/LocalService.dart:11:41)
#8      main (package:indonesia_bisa_2/Main/main.dart:16:14)
#9      _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure>.<…>
```

heres the checker code

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

Future<void> save_loggedIn() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString("loggedIn", "true");
}

//this is for checking the saved variable to check if the user is already logged in or not
Future<String> read_loggedIn() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var value = prefs.getString("loggedIn");
  return value;
}
```

and here is when the code used

```
Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: (read_loggedIn() == "true") ? new SPAL (): new MyApp()));
}
```

Comment: show me your full code of LocalService.dart file.

Comment: @SaifulIslam the full LocalService.dart is the checker code

Comment: could you tell me which line is the number 11 line?

Comment: @SaifulIslam `final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();`

Comment: okay i got your problem.

Comment: @SaifulIslam can you help me?

Comment: sure. wait please

Comment: hey i posted an answer please let me know if its worked or not.

Comment: @SaifulIslam I comment on your answer

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Make sure to call `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` before `await SharedPreferences.getInstance();`

For example in your main.dart:

```
void main() async {
  await runZonedGuarded(
    () async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      runApp(MyApp(prefs));
    },
    (error, st) => print(error),
  );
}
```

Comment: Just a call to `WidgetFlutterBinding.ensureIntialized()` does the trick

Comment: Just to help anyone in the same situation: in addition to the solution stated above, I had also added a new plugin and the problem remained until I completely stopped the app and restarted it.

Answer (score 1):

I got the exact same error, when I tested my application with iphone simulator. (I have a m1 mac). It may have been a "timing issue".
I added this line *await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));* before SharedPreferences.getInstance and the error disappeared.

Comment: Thanks a ton. You saved my day :) 
I've got the same issue. It's about delayed logic.

Comment: This solved the issue. Didn't knew SharedPreferences won't be ready instantly for awaiting.

Answer (score 0):

you can change `main` method like this:

```dart
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

Future<void> save_loggedIn() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  prefs.setBool("loggedIn", true);
}

Future<Bool> read_loggedIn() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var value = prefs.getBool("loggedIn");

  return value;
}

Future<void> main() async {
  final bool login = await read_loggedIn();

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: (login ?? false) ? SPAL() : MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you called `read_loggedIn()` which is a future but you called it directly and while its not returning value you got a null value. So you have to `await` until you get the result from `read_loggedIn()` and then you can use its value.

Replace your main method with bellow code

```
Future<void> main() async {

    // you have to wait untill get the result
    var login = await read_loggedIn();
    
    runApp(new MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        // and you must check if your login value is null or not
        home: (login != null && login == "true") ? new SPAL(): new MyApp()));
}
```

Comment: i got another error and it keeps me on a blank screen

Comment: you could see my full code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67785543/keeping-the-user-logged-in

Comment: if this answer helped you them mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: that may be for another reason. but if you mark it as accepted it going to help other developers. but it's your own wish. good luck.

Comment: i will take a look on your other problem but now I am on my job. so bye for a while. catch you latter. thank you.

Comment: No problem!, Thank you so much for helping!, Ill be waiting for you.